# How do I get the MAX of two values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the max number of two numbers and I figured that I cannot do it like this `SELECT MAX(2, 4)`.

I did try to do it like this but got an error. `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

```
SELECT  MAX( (SELECT LEN('tests') as value
            UNION ALL
            SELECT LEN('test') as value) );
```

How can I overcome this or achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do `MAX(2,4)`; `MAX` only expects one parameter.

For something simple like this, you can use a `CASE` expression. For example:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN A > B THEN A ELSE B END
```

Note this assumes neither value can be `NULL`. If they can be, then would do something like this:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN B IS NULL OR A > B THEN A
            ELSE B
       END
```

For more complex scenarios, you can use a subquery to unpivot the data:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT MAX(V.V)
        FROM(VALUES(A),(B),(C),(D),(E),(F),(G))V(V))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=d43c1de8c020e19664ad4ec01ae33b3f)

Answer (score 0):

A small change will do: give the `UNION ALL` result a **name**, and then query from it. I used the name `union_result`, you can of course pick just about any name you like.

```
SELECT MAX(union_result.value)
FROM (SELECT LEN('tests') as value
      UNION ALL
      SELECT LEN('test') as value
     ) AS union_result
```